# Types.py Error, Renaming issues, AttributeError

Tags: python, cmd, attributeerror

Recently I've been having trouble typing 'python' into cmd. It would give me an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 62, in <module>
import os
File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 398, in <module>
import UserDict
File "C:\Python27\lib\UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
import _abcoll
File "C:\Python27\lib\_abcoll.py", line 70, in <module>
Iterable.register(str)
File "C:\Python27\lib\abc.py", line 107, in register
if not isinstance(subclass, (type, types.ClassType)):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ClassType'
```

Someone told me to rename a file in my sys.path, called types.py. I renamed a types.py in my Lib folder under the Python27 directory, and it still hasn't changed. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: "Someone" has been giving you very bad advice. You should never modify the files inside python/Lib.

Comment: Well do you know how to fix the error?

Comment: But that doesn't fix the problem?

Comment: Then reinstall. What did you hope to achieve anyway?

Comment: I did reinstall, I reinstalled a ton, and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

seems like you have created one file with name "abc.py", if yes then please rename. then it should work. :)